# c++ priority_queue loses order when inserting an element greater than the current one

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have `std::priotity_queue` that I implemented with a custom comparison function. When testing it, I experienced a weird behavior. I insert the first element, then the second, which should go in front of the first after running the comparison, which it does meaning the comparison function works as expected. When inserting a third element, which should now also go tot the top of the queue, after `std::priority_queue.push()` returns, instead of the queue looking like this : third-second-first; it looks like this : third-first-second.

Looking with the debugger I saw that before the comparison gets run, the new element gets first added at the end of the queue. And since after the comparison the second added element ends at the end of the queue it means that the third instead of getting inserted before the second inserted element, it gets swapped with it.

Any idea why this is happening? I don't think this is expected behavior. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
struct Position {
    int turns;
    int cabin;
    int index;

    static bool comparePosition(Position const left, Position const right) {
        if (left.turns != right.turns)
            return left.turns > right.turns;
        else
            return left.cabin > right.cabin;
    }
};


Position order(std::vector<int> const &c, int const n, int const p) {
    std::priority_queue<Position, std::vector<Position>, decltype(&Position::comparePosition)> queue(
            Position::comparePosition);
    int cabina = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
        if (cabina <= n) {
            
            queue.push(Position{c[i], cabina, i});
            cabina++;
        } else {
            
            Position out = queue.top();
            cout << out.index + 1 << ' ';
            queue.pop();
            queue.push(Position{c[i], out.cabin, i});

        }

    }
    

    Position out{};
    while (!queue.empty()) {
        out = queue.top();
        queue.pop();
        cout << out.index << ' ';
    }

    
    return out;

}
```

Comment: the reason for what your code does is most likely in your code. Please include a [mcve] in the quesiton

Comment: sounds like your comparison function is broken, but thats just a guess

Comment: Added the code. Also, the comp. function gets it's parameters by value now, tried by ref as well, same behavior

Comment: std::priority_queue does not need to maintain sortedness, it (typically) maintains the [heap property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Comment: This means that when I pop the first element, the next greatest element will come first even though it wasn't the second  at that time?

Comment: @AdrianPascu yes, that's correct - that's why pop() is O(log n) time.